# Promise fired before waiting for result

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, electron, bluebird

I'm very new to promises and my following code produces some unexpected results but I don't know why.

The Taskrunner.SyncObjects function in Main.js should wait for the filled selectedCourses variable, but instead of that it just fires instantly. This results in an empty selectedCourses variable being used.

Why is it that the TaskRuner.SyncObjects function runs before having a result?

**Main.js**

```
function StartSync(){

var a = Settings.LoadCourseList(standardOSPathUserData);
var b = a.then(function(){
    console.log("b is running");
    var selectedCourses = Settings.courseList;

    return TaskRunner.SyncObjects(selectedCourses).then(function(){
        fileSyncRunning = false;
    });
}).catch(function(error){
    console.log("StartSync Error message: " + error);
});

}
```

**Settings.js**

```
Settings.LoadCourseList = function(osPath){
  var pathToCourseListSettings = osPath + courseListFileName;
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
            try {
                return connection.Login().then(function(){
                    return connection.GetCourseList().then(function(result){
                        var allCourses = [];
                        for(var p=0; p<=result.length-1;p++){
                          allCourses.push({courseID: result[p].courseID, courseName: result[p].courseName, selected: true});
                        }
                        courseListJSON = JSON.stringify(allCourses);
                        return courseListJSON;
                    }).then(function(courseListJSON){
                        fs.appendFileSync(pathToCourseListSettings,courseListJSON,encoding='utf8');
                        console.log("New Course settings file created and filled: " + pathToCourseListSettings);
                        return resolve();
                    });
                }).then(function(){
                    return resolve();
                });
            } catch (e) {
                console.log("FAIL courseList settingsfile creation - Error: " + e.code);
                return reject(e);
            }
  });
};
```

Comment: What is `TaskRunner.SyncObjects`?

Comment: @trincot That is a promise function which I can't publish the code of. Do you think the issue lies in this function? The results need to be defined before the "TaskRunner.SyncObjects" function, so the internal workings of this function doesn't matter. Right?

Comment: Indeed, if you expect results before `SyncObjects` is run then it has nothing to do with that function. I misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears Settings.courseList is never assigned a value in Settings.js

You could try adding

```
Settings.courseList = allCourses;
```

on the line before

```
courseListJSON = JSON.stringify(allCourses);
```

Or better yet you could do it the promise way and resolve the promise with allCourses.

To make the promise from Settings.LoadCourseList(standardOSPathUserData); return allCourse, change

```
return connection.Login().then(function(){
    return connection.GetCourseList().then(function(result){
        var allCourses = [];
        for(var p=0; p<=result.length-1;p++){
          allCourses.push({courseID: result[p].courseID, courseName: result[p].courseName, selected: true});
        }
        courseListJSON = JSON.stringify(allCourses);
        return courseListJSON;
    }).then(function(courseListJSON){
        fs.appendFileSync(pathToCourseListSettings,courseListJSON,encoding='utf8');
        console.log("New Course settings file created and filled: " + pathToCourseListSettings);
        return resolve();
    });
}).then(function(){
    return resolve();
});
```

to

```
return connection.Login().then(function(){
    return connection.GetCourseList().then(function(result){
        var allCourses = [];
        for(var p=0; p<=result.length-1;p++){
          allCourses.push({courseID: result[p].courseID, courseName: result[p].courseName, selected: true});
        }
        var courseListJSON = JSON.stringify(allCourses);
        fs.appendFileSync(pathToCourseListSettings,courseListJSON,encoding='utf8');
        console.log("New Course settings file created and filled: " + pathToCourseListSettings);
        return allCourses;
    });
});
```

and to receive that promise result change

```
var b = a.then(function(){
    console.log("b is running");
    var selectedCourses = Settings.courseList;
```

to

```
var b = a.then(function(allCourses){
    console.log("b is running");
    var selectedCourses = allCourses;
```

Comment: I can't believe that slipped through... I was so in doubt about my promises I did not pay attention to that small, but very important detail. Thank you so much!!! Adding the "Settings.courseList = allCourses;" did the trick.